# How can a male drow change sex?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, drow, gender

I am currently playing as a drow male that has the ambition to eventually return to his homeland and take over the rulership of his house, but the thing is my drow is male and a male drow cannot inherit. Should he marry, the power will simply go to his wife. So my character is currently trying to find a way to change his sex permanently.

I am looking for a solution that can be bought with gold if possible. Currently the only solution I'm aware of is [girdle of opposite gender](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items#TOC-Girdle-of-Opposite-Gender) which cannot be bought. I would also prefer it if the solution was not possible to dispel because if it was then my character's opponents could simply use dispel magic on him in order to make him lose his position.

Comment: It's a good idea to ask your DM about drow society before you go ahead with this. It might be considered cheating.

Comment: @JohnDallman especially since the elixir posted below is cheap enough to raise questions of "why aren't lots of others doing it?" and female drow aren't likely to welcome extra competition.

Comment: @JohnDallman: As long as you don't get caught while cheating, I would say Lolth will be intrigued and one might get away with it. The PC might need to claim "she" is a lost heiress to the matron mother's throne.

Comment: @JohnDallman Yeah, this sounds like a total anathema in the drow society and a sacrilege against Lolth. The possibility of changing genders at will would erode the very concept of gender, which is one of the pillars of the drow social constructs. I don't think Lolth would ever allow such a thing and the unfortunate drow would rather search for a potion to turn back from a drider form...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Elixir of Sex Shifting

Found in the Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Advanced Class Guide (or [here on d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/elixir-of-sex-shifting/)):

> Upon drinking this elixir, a character permanently transforms their biology to take on a different set of sexual characteristics of their choice...
>
> This elixir’s magic functions instantaneously and can’t be dispelled...

Comment: How to mess with the spider goddess 101 :D